# List index is out of range and I do not understand why?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, error-handling, pygame

I've been getting the error :

`line 102, in <module>
    shot[2] += shoty
IndexError: list index out of range`

In my code where I am trying to code a dagger to be thrown, and deleted if it is out of bounds. I understand what the list error means however; I am unsure of how it is affecting my code and any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the part of my code which is relevant to the problem:

```
daggers = []
daggerPlayer = pygame.image.load(daggerImage.png)

    for shot in daggers:
    index = 0
    shotx = math.cos(shot[0])*10
    shoty = math.sin(shot[0])*10
    shot[1] += shotx
    shot[2] += shoty
    if (shot[1] < -64) or (shot[1] > 900) or (shot[2] < -64) or (shot[2]> 600):
        daggers.pop(index)
    index +=1

    for shoot in daggers:
        daggerOne = pygame.transform.rotate(daggerPlayer, 360 - shoot[0]*57.29)
        screen.blit(daggerOne, (shoot[1], shoot[2]))
```

EDIT: Here is the entirety of my code

```
#Load Images
peterPlayer = pygame.image.load('pixelPirateOne.png)'
nightBackground = pygame.image.load ('NightSky.png')
daggerPlayer = pygame.image.load('daggerImage.png')

#Settting Variables for Moving Character
xPlayer = 200
yPlayer = 275
dxPlayer = 0
dyPlayer = 0
playerPosition = (200,275)
accuracyShot = [0,0]
daggers = []

def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

go = True
while go:

#Blit The Background    
    screen.blit(nightBackground, (0,0))

#Learned about atan2 from --> https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html
#Allows To Rotate Player With Mouse    
    mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()   
    angle = math.atan2(mousePosition[1]-(yPlayer+32),mousePosition[0]-(xPlayer+26))
    playerRotate = pygame.transform.rotate(peterPlayer, 360-angle*57.29)
    playerPositionNew = (xPlayer-playerRotate.get_rect().width/2, yPlayer-playerRotate.get_rect().height/2)
    screen.blit(playerRotate, playerPositionNew)
    pygame.display.update()

#Quit Game
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quitGame()

#Move Player- Note: Make this portion fluid; it's choppy as of now                
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                dxPlayer -= 15
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dxPlayer += 15
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dyPlayer -= 15
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dyPlayer += 15

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dxPlayer = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dyPlayer = 0

        xPlayer = xPlayer + dxPlayer
        yPlayer = yPlayer + dyPlayer
        pygame.display.update()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()   
            accuracyShot[1] += 1
            daggers.append([math.atan2(mousePosition[1]-(playerPositionNew[1]+32), mousePosition[0]-(playerPositionNew[0]+26)), playerPositionNew[1]+32]) 

#Learned about cos and sin in python from --> https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html
#Learned about .pop from --> https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html
    for shot in daggers:
        index = 0
        shotx = math.cos(shot[0])*10
        shoty = math.sin(shot[0])*10
        shot[1] += shotx
        shot[2] += shoty
        if (shot[1] < -64) or (shot[1] > 900) or (shot[2] < -64) or (shot[2]> 600):
            daggers.pop(index)
        index +=1

        for shoot in daggers:
            daggerOne = pygame.transform.rotate(daggerPlayer, 360 - shoot[0]*57.29)
            screen.blit(daggerOne, (shoot[1], shoot[2]))
```

Comment: can you also add the example value of `daggers`?

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't quite understand? Do you mean where daggers in appended in the code?

Comment: I've added the entirety of my code apart from initializing the screen and importing. Hope it is now clearer!

Comment: I did try that, however when I change it to 0 and 1; I no longer get the error, however the image is not even shown on the screen

Answer (score 0):

The list you append to daggers has only two elements, but by calling `shot[2]` you are trying to access the third, that's why you get that error. The two elements should be shot[0] and shot[1]. I believe you make the same mistake in `screen.blit(daggerOne, (shoot[1], shoot[2]))` as well.